# Attachment Handling through WSO2 EI 6.1.1 in API

Tags: wso2, postman, attachment, wso2-enterprise-integrator, zoho

**Use Case:**

- A REST API will be defined to handle the files sent by clients called (Postman REST Client) as attachment.
- The files sent as attachment will be sent to [Zoho Task Creation Endpoint](https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/tasks-api.html#alink4) in order to create task with Document.

**Note**: When i tried with postman directly by calling [Zoho task Creation API](https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/tasks-api.html#alink4), It creates task with Document.

Can anyone please let me know how to achieve this in API of WSO2 EI 6.1.1

**Postman:**

[image: Postman Client]

When i put log level="full" inside api,getting below log.

[image: Log level Full]

When i decode it via [Online Tool](https://www.base64decode.org/) which gives base64 decoded content like below.

[image]

**API Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/uploadAttachment" name="AtatchmentAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
         <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="multipart/form-data"/>
       <!--  <log level="full"/> -->
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="========UploadAttachment" value=" API Called=========="/>
                <property name="========AttachmentName===" expression="get-property('transport', 'filename')"/>
                
            </log>
           <property expression="get-property('registry','gov:/ZohoConfig/ZohoAppConfigFile.txt')" name="accessToken" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <!-- <log level="full"/> -->
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
              <format>
                <ns:binary xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">$1</ns:binary>
              </format>
              <args>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//*[local-name()='binary']/text()"/>
              </args>
            </payloadFactory>
             <script language="js">
            <![CDATA[
               var binaryNode =       
                  mc.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstElement().getFirstOMChild();  
               binaryNode.setBinary(true);
            ]]>
            </script>
            <property name="attachment_base64" expression="$body"/>
            <log level="custom">
            <property name="====attachment_base64====" expression="$body"></property>
            </log>
            <payloadFactory description="Form Response Payload" media-type="json">
               <format>{"uploaddoc":$1}</format>
               <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:attachment_base64"/>
                </args>  
           </payloadFactory>
           <log level="custom">
            <property name="====uploaddoc_Payload====" expression="$body"></property>
            </log>
            <!-- <log level="full"/> -->
             <property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" value="ZohoTestFile.txt" scope="transport"/>
             <property name="transport.vfs.Streaming" value="true" scope="transport"/>
             <property name="ClientApiNonBlocking" action="remove" scope="axis2"/>
             <property name="messageType" scope="axis2"  value="application/binary"/>
            <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
             <header expression="fn:concat('Bearer ', '1000.CCCCCCCCCC.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')" name="Authorization" scope="transport"/>
             <call>
             <endpoint>
             <address uri="https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/36249112/projects/685798000000976352/tasks/685798000011774999/attachments/"/>
             </endpoint>
             </call>
              <log>
               <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="==API Response======"/>
           </log>
             <!-- <payloadFactory description="Form Response Payload" media-type="json">
               <format>{"recipients":"Regularrrrrrrrrrrrr"}</format>
               <args/>
                  
           </payloadFactory>
           <log>
               <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="==Final- CampaignBuilder_JsonRequest_ForCreation======"/>
           </log> -->
        <respond/>
            <!-- <property expression="String(//mediate/file/@filename)" name="filename" scope="default" type="STRING"/> -->
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

**API Response:**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 6831,
        "message": "Input Parameter Missing"
    }
}
```

**Reason:** need to pass attachment to the param called "uploaddoc" when calling Zoho API. here i don't know how to set attachment to that field

**Wire Logs:**

```
    3:04:42,565] []  INFO - APIDeployer API named 'AtatchmentAPI' has been deployed from file : D:\ServerSetup 6.1.1\wso2ei-6.1.1\wso2\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1602833682469Att
-CAR_1.0.0.car\AtatchmentAPI_1.0.0\AtatchmentAPI-1.0.0.xml
3:04:42,565] []  INFO - ApplicationManager Successfully Deployed Carbon Application : AttachmentUpload-CAR_1.0.0 {super-tenant}
3:05:04,362] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "POST /uploadAttachment HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,363] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.5[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,363] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,363] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Postman-Token: 21c46ad2-19fc-46a6-aea8-8113ac70817e[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,363] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Host: localhost:8280[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,363] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,364] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,364] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------623932778277436708655778[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,364] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Cookie: bf42f62d55=64dc75f94d2bd72d94493d263847c08c[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,364] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Content-Length: 376[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,365] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,365] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "----------------------------623932778277436708655778[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,365] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaddoc"; filename="ZohoAttachment.txt"[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,365] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Content-Type: text/plain[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,366] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,370] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Hi,[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,371] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "This is zoho Attachment task[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,371] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "----------------------------623932778277436708655778[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,371] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,373] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,373] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "TaskAttachment Demo[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,373] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "----------------------------623932778277436708655778--[\r][\n]"
3:05:04,373] []  INFO - LogMediator ========UploadAttachment =  API Called==========, ========AttachmentName=== = null
3:05:04,398] []  INFO - LogMediator ====attachment_base64==== = <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><ns:binary xmlns:ns="http://ws.apa
ns/ns/payload">LS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLTYyMzkzMjc3ODI3NzQzNjcwODY1NTc3OA0KQ29udGVudC1EaXNwb3NpdGlvbjogZm9ybS1kYXRhOyBuYW1lPSJ1cGxvYWRkb2MiOyBmaWxlbmFtZT0iW
1lbnQudHh0Ig0KQ29udGVudC1UeXBlOiB0ZXh0L3BsYWluDQoNCkhpLA0KVGhpcyBpcyB6b2hvIEF0dGFjaG1lbnQgdGFzaw0KLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLTYyMzkzMjc3ODI3NzQzNjcwODY1NTc3OA
EaXNwb3NpdGlvbjogZm9ybS1kYXRhOyBuYW1lPSJuYW1lIg0KDQpUYXNrQXR0YWNobWVudCBEZW1vDQotLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tNjIzOTMyNzc4Mjc3NDM2NzA4NjU1Nzc4LS0NCg==</ns:binary
dy>
3:05:04,402] []  INFO - LogMediator ====uploaddoc_Payload==== = <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><uploaddoc xmlns="http://ws.apache
se">LS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLTYyMzkzMjc3ODI3NzQzNjcwODY1NTc3OA0KQ29udGVudC1EaXNwb3NpdGlvbjogZm9ybS1kYXRhOyBuYW1lPSJ1cGxvYWRkb2MiOyBmaWxlbmFtZT0iWm9ob0F0dGFj
g0KQ29udGVudC1UeXBlOiB0ZXh0L3BsYWluDQoNCkhpLA0KVGhpcyBpcyB6b2hvIEF0dGFjaG1lbnQgdGFzaw0KLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLTYyMzkzMjc3ODI3NzQzNjcwODY1NTc3OA0KQ29udGVud
lvbjogZm9ybS1kYXRhOyBuYW1lPSJuYW1lIg0KDQpUYXNrQXR0YWNobWVudCBEZW1vDQotLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tNjIzOTMyNzc4Mjc3NDM2NzA4NjU1Nzc4LS0NCg==</uploaddoc></soapenv:

3:05:05,124] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "POST /restapi/portal/36249008/projects/685798000009576352/tasks/685798000011774013/attachments/ HTTP/1.1[

3:05:05,126] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Authorization: Bearer 1000.9df1f22e7d16ba95f0553af9855d40b5.f81f2af95682c8b398d0bb4939190d10[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,127] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Cookie: bf42f62d55=64dc75f94d2bd72d94493d263847c08c[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,127] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "transport.vfs.Streaming: true[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,127] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,128] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Postman-Token: 21c46ad2-19fc-46a6-aea8-8113ac70817e[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,128] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,128] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "transport.vfs.ReplyFileName: ZohoTestFile.txt[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,129] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Content-Type: application/binary[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,129] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,129] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Host: projectsapi.zoho.com[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,130] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,130] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,130] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,131] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "237[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,131] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "<uploaddoc xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">LS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLTYyMzkzMjc3ODI3Nz
3OA0KQ29udGVudC1EaXNwb3NpdGlvbjogZm9ybS1kYXRhOyBuYW1lPSJ1cGxvYWRkb2MiOyBmaWxlbmFtZT0iWm9ob0F0dGFjaG1lbnQudHh0Ig0KQ29udGVudC1UeXBlOiB0ZXh0L3BsYWluDQoNCkhpLA0KVGhpcyBpcyB
aG1lbnQgdGFzaw0KLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLTYyMzkzMjc3ODI3NzQzNjcwODY1NTc3OA0KQ29udGVudC1EaXNwb3NpdGlvbjogZm9ybS1kYXRhOyBuYW1lPSJuYW1lIg0KDQpUYXNrQXR0YWNobWVu
S0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tNjIzOTMyNzc4Mjc3NDM2NzA4NjU1Nzc4LS0NCg==</uploaddoc>[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,134] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "0[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,135] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,905] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "HTTP/1.1 400 [\r][\n]"
3:05:05,906] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Server: ZGS[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,906] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Date: Fri, 16 Oct 2020 07:35:06 GMT[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,906] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,906] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Content-Length: 60[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,907] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,907] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,907] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "X-XSS-Protection: 1[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,908] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Set-Cookie: zpct=24a027ad-3cd2-4edf-b641-b792d3ffede8;path=/;SameSite=None;Secure;priority=high[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,908] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Set-Cookie: _zcsr_tmp=24a027ad-3cd2-4edf-b641-b792d3ffede8;path=/;SameSite=Strict;Secure;priority=high[\r

3:05:05,908] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,909] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,909] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,909] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=9FD064E43DACD49060E958A34C2E0325; Path=/; Secure[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,909] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,910] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "X-UA-Compatible: IE=9, IE=10[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,910] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=response.txt;[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,910] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "X-Download-Options: noopen[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,910] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,910] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "{"error":{"code":6831,"message":"Input Parameter Missing"}}[\n]"
3:05:05,921] []  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:49cdf6b1-0ac6-4728-bc92-f8658b4a88
: request, ==API Response====== = {"error":{"code":6831,"message":"Input Parameter Missing"}}

3:05:05,925] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "HTTP/1.1 400 [\r][\n]"
3:05:05,925] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,925] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "X-UA-Compatible: IE=9, IE=10[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,926] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,927] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,927] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=response.txt;[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,927] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "X-Download-Options: noopen[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,927] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=9FD064E43DACD49060E958A34C2E0325; Path=/; Secure[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,927] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Set-Cookie: _zcsr_tmp=24a027ad-3cd2-4edf-b641-b792d3ffede8;path=/;SameSite=Strict;Secure;priority=high[\

3:05:05,928] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Set-Cookie: zpct=24a027ad-3cd2-4edf-b641-b792d3ffede8;path=/;SameSite=None;Secure;priority=high[\r][\n]"

3:05:05,928] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,929] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,929] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "X-XSS-Protection: 1[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,929] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,930] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Date: Fri, 16 Oct 2020 07:35:05 GMT[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,930] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,930] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Connection: Close[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,930] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,931] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "3c[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,931] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "{"error":{"code":6831,"message":"Input Parameter Missing"}}[\n]"
3:05:05,931] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,931] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "0[\r][\n]"
3:05:05,932] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "[\r][\n]"
```

Can Anyone please give me a solution for this?

Comment: You can call the API in the EI the same way you're calling the backend endpoint, with the file attachment. EI will forward the attachment to the endpoint, given your API calls that endpoint.

Comment: Hi @ThishaniLucas
Thanks for your information. my doubt here is how can i fetch attachment comes from RESTClient(Postman) inside our API?"uploaddoc" is the key in which attachment("ZohoAttachment.txt") is added . As per above Postman screenshot need to pass attachment to the "uploaddoc" field when calling external endpoint. can you pls help me?Awaiting for your response..

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code you are not doing anything with the incoming payload. so why are you trying to mediate the payload? just pass through it.

Comment: Hi @Krishantha Dinesh,
I need to pass incoming request(ie attachment content) to the field called "uploaddoc". follows (https://medium.com/@nwijesekare/document-handling-through-api-using-wso2-enterprise-integrator-79f803df2673 or https://medium.com/think-integration/construct-and-send-multipart-form-data-using-wso2-ei-5cd548d095ee) while calling zoho api. can you please share code base in order  to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Mock zoho api (use any simple python, pip install web server) and dump request came from ESB and see what is missing in request. Some of the header most probably missing, Content-Disposition Content-Type

API states "name" parameter is mandatory.

Comment: Hi @simar,
For creating task, that "name" is mandatory. i have called add attachment endpoint(https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/tasks-api.html#add-attachments) instead of creating task with attachment(https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/tasks-api.html#alink4). why i tried with attachment alone is, if attachment goes in right manner,i can integrate it with creating task with attachment process.

Comment: Hi @simar,
i received like "Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaddoc"; filename="ZohoAttachment.txt"[\r][\n]"  and "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------623932778277436708655778[\r][\n]" in WIRE LOG. but don't know what are all the required things are missing.

Comment: It hard to predict and see why service on wso doesn't work. Obviously since you able to make success request using external tool, there is a difference between how wso sent http request and external tool. That's why usually in testing purpose configure either to send to mock service so you can see request itself or force it to pass over proxy (tcpcatcher.org or google burp suite). Last solution can make you play with request and modify to see what changes need to fulfill request.

Comment: Hi @simar,
not having much idea about google burb suite. will below link helpful for me?https://www.4armed.com/blog/google-chrome-proxy-through-burp-suite/ or pls share useful link in order to check headers information . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes burp sute is http proxy that will help you to catch, examine and modify request/response.

Comment: Hi @simar,
unfortunately i can't able to enable this kind of setting in my chrome, getting message like "Web Page Blocked!You have tried to access a web page which is in violation of your internet usage policy."

Comment: Well it is not chome you must enfoce wso make http request over proxy. Wso use apache http commons (HttpClient) that must be configured to use proxy.